# Parsing array data

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, json

I am trying to parse this array data that way generated from JQuery and JSON.

```
Array
(
[d] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [order] => 1
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [order] => 2
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [order] => 3
            )

        [3] => Array
            (
                [order] => 4
            )

        [4] => Array
            (
                [order] => 5
            )

    )

)
```

I am trying to save the above date into a mysql table, but cannot seem to parse the data properly to be inserted into the database.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

I suppose language is PHP?
You might wanna take a look json_decode()-function here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Answer (score 0):

This looks like the ouput of the function [**`print_r()`**](http://www.php.net/print_r) -- and **this is not intented to be parsed**.

Instead of trying to parse that, you should work directly with the data your PHP code is receiving from the Ajax request -- i.e. with the JSON data, decoded with [**`json_decode()`**](http://www.php.net/json_decode).

Comment: WOW, such quick replies...

This is what is sent through the AJAX POST:

    {"d":[{"order":1},{"order":2},{"order":3},{"order":4},{"order":5}]}

And using json_decode, the code below is what I have so far:

    $data = file_get_contents('php://input');
    $data = json_decode(utf8_decode($data), true);

    foreach ( $data[d] as $key => $value )
    {
        // $this->img_model->update_image_order($id , $order);
    }

My main problem is getting my head round the arrays...  Hopefully someone can point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is something like this,

```
foreach ( $data['d'] as $key => $value ) { 
   $id = $value['order'];
   $order = 'order';
   $this->img_model->update_image_order($id , $order); 
}
```

This assumes the number in JSON is the order ID.

Comment: Thanks ZZCoder, unfortunately I am getting a couple of errors with this.  I am getting "Message:  Use of undefined constant d - assumed 'd" and "Message:  Undefined variable: order" errors.

How can I fix this?

Comment: I don't know the semantics of the message so the code is just an example how to handle the array of array. Just edited to get rid of the errors.

Answer (score 0):

You should use json_decode() (as others have already stated) for decoding your JSON into php arrays.
But if I got it right your problem is how to work with PHP arrays so i suggest you check out some good basic tutorial. w3c has decent basic array tutorial here: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_arrays.asp